# Hyperlink <a> tag not behaving as I expect in html

Tags: html, css

1. I created a div and inside div I added a hypertag element `<a>`
2. When I give a margin for the `<a>` tag it moves the `<div>` tag instead of `<a>` tag
3. I do not understand this behaviour. Could you please check this issue .

```css
.first {
  color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: cyan;
}

a {
  margin: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="result">Explore Google With Prevent Default</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Explore Google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the correct behavior in Chrome and Firefox Win11.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing